# External libs Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I have customized a package of Android framework and built it.

In Eclipse I was using it by first going to Java Build path - > Libraries - > Remove existing android.jar, add my customized jar and then select Add Library for sdk's Android jar.

This work around was because, by default code will import from sdk's jar.

By this workaround, when we remove sdk's jar and add our customized jar,  code vil import dependencies from our jar. 
Then adding sdk jar will resolve other dependencies.

Can someone tell me how to achieve this on Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your project -> Open Module Settings -> select your app module -> Dependencies tab